# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'from_square'

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing this small program for chess, and it is giving me an error, in the title. I am new to python though :D

```
import chess
import chess.engine
import time
engine = chess.engine.SimpleEngine.popen_uci("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\sf.exe") #Stockfish

side = 1
i=0
board = chess.Board()
while True:
    chess.engine.turn = side # This isn't working
    if(side == 0): #
        res = input("Enter your enemie's move: ")
        board.push(res)
        side = not side
        i+=1
    else:
        i += 1
        result = engine.play(board,chess.engine.Limit(time=0.1))
        print(result.move)
        board.push(result.move)
        side = not side

    time.sleep(1)
exit()
```

So, the res is the input move, which is just 4 characters. For example - h7h5
Log from the console:

```
e2e4
Enter your enemie's move: e7e5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    board.push(res)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py", line 1954, in push
    move = self._to_chess960(move)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\chess\__init__.py", line 3334, in _to_chess960
    if move.from_square == E1 and self.kings & BB_E1:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'from_square'
```

Comment: Please add the code for `Board.push()` method.

Comment: I guess, you can find it here - https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/v0.30.1/_modules/chess/engine.html#EngineProtocol
Search for: class EngineProtocol(asyncio.SubprocessProtocol, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

Comment: Oh sorry, don't know why I assumed it would be your code.

Comment: That's ok. Maybe you could help with  chess.engine.turn = side? It is not working. I enter a side, but it does not change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to turn the input string into a `Move` object.

```
res = input("Enter your enemie's move: ")
move = chess.Move.from_uci(res)
board.push(move)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the doc](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/core.html), you should try to use `push_san` instead of `push`.

Or if you still want to use `push`, you have to create a `Move` instance:

```
import chess

board = chess.Board()

Nf3 = chess.Move.from_uci("g1f3")
board.push(Nf3)  # Make the move
```